# How to set float to variable with 7 digits after the decimal point in arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Example:

```
float x = 3154681.124 / 100000; //x = 31.54;
```

I want x to be:

```
x = 31.5468112;
```

Comment: When you write `3154681.124 / 100000`, you are accumulating two rounding errors: first, in representing the numerator as a float, then in the division. Total error ≈ 1.09e-6. If you write instead `31.54681124` you have a single rounding error, and the total error is 25% lower.

Comment: An IEEE 32 bit float has only 23 bits for the fractional part, so you only get about log(2^23)/log(10)=6.9 decimal places total.  Maybe you want a double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `float` type has slightly over 7 digits of precision. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point.

> I want x to be:
>
> ```
>    x = 31.5468112;
> ```

Bad luck. That's 9 digits of precision. You can get around 7 digits by converting it appropriately, eg. as Majenko said:

```c++
  float x = 3154681.124 / 100000; //x = 31.54;
  Serial.println(x, 7);
```

However that printed:

```
31.5468101
```

It got 7 digits right, as advertised.

---

You can use the [BigNumber Library](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11519) that I wrote. Available from [GitHub](https://github.com/nickgammon/BigNumber).

Using that, you can get all the precision you want, within reason:

```
#include "BigNumber.h"

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();

  BigNumber::begin (7);  // 7 digits after the decimal place

  BigNumber x ("3154681.124");
  BigNumber y = x / BigNumber ("100000");
  
  Serial.println(y);
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  }  // end of loop
```

Output:

```
31.5468112
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float x = 3154681.124 / 100000; //x = 31.54;
```

`x` is now `31.5468112` (or close to).

```
Serial.println(x);
```

Output: `31.54`

Why? Because `Serial.println` defaults to 2 decimal places for floats.

> Syntax
>
> `Serial.println(val)`
>
> `Serial.println(val, format)`
>
> Parameters
>
> `val`: the value to print - any data type
>
> `format`: specifies the number base (for integral data types) **or number of decimal places (for floating point types)**

So the solution: specift 7 decimal places when you print:

```
Serial.println(x, 7);
```

Comment: I don't want to print **x** , I want to send it as a parameter in URL to web service. when I send it as **x** its value became `31.54`

Comment: Then whatever your code is that is doing the sending is truncating it. I can't see that code, so I can't advise on it. The simple fact, though, is a float doesn't have a fixed number of decimal places, that's not how floats work.

Comment: `when I send it as x its value became 31.54` - you need to post that code. We can't answer questions about code we can't see.